# Speed of light different in different directions; simple refutation is looking at stars in different directions?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pTn6Ewhb27k), Veretasium posits that you can only measure the speed of light by assuming that its the same in different directions. He says this is just a convention (quoting Einstein). No one can ever know if its true. But then at 14:12 in the video, he mentions how looking in one direction, you'd see things in their past and looking in another direction, in their less distant past or even present. But isn't this an obvious refutation of the statement? If the speed of light were different in different directions, we would see different looking universes depending on the direction we looked. The stars in one direction would be younger than another; the cosmic background radiation would be different. Isn't this an obvious refutation of this idea of different speeds in different directions? Did he miss this or am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If the speed of light were different in different directions, we would see different looking universes depending on the direction we looked. The stars in one direction would be younger than another; the cosmic background radiation would be different. Isn't this an obvious refutation of this idea of different speeds in different directions? Did he miss this or am I missing something?

This one-way anisotropy in the speed of light is sometimes called “conspiratorial anisotropy”. There is always some other anisotropic effect that conspires with the speed of light to produce isotropic observations. Since the observations depend on both, it is impossible to refute the conspiracy.

In this case, we observe isotropy in the apparent age of stars at a given distance. The apparent age of stars depends on the distance, the speed of light, and the actual age. The actual age depends on time dilation, in regions with more time dilation the stars will be younger.

If light from younger stars reaches us faster then the effects of anisotropic time dilation will conspire with the effects of the anisotropic one way speed of light to produce the isotropic observation. Since cosmic conspiracies of this sort, by design, have no observational consequences we can always ignore them and choose the isotropic convention.  But it is just a convention.

Comment: But time dilation only applies when things move, right? Couldn't we carefully select objects that don't move relative to us?

Comment: @Rohit Pandey not in cosmology. The objects that we observe in cosmology are all physically moving away from us.

Comment: But that happens to be a feature of our particular universe which is orthogonal to the constancy of the speed of light. A static universe is consistent with relativity, correct (in fact, Einstein thought it was the case)? So in such a hypothetical universe we would be able to tell if the speed were different in different directions? And this confuses me even more because if Einstein believed the universe was static, he should have known to simply use my argument instead of calling it a convention?

Comment: @Rohit Pandey “So in such a hypothetical universe we would be able to tell if the speed were different in different directions?” This is a whole different question. Comments aren’t for extended discussion or new questions. If you want discussion instead of straight Q&A then I recommend physicsforums.com

Comment: I don't feel my original question has been answered. Ill just ask a new one. Thanks!

Comment: @Rohit Pandey your original question asked about this universe, including the CMB. Not some hypothetical static universe. How can you say it wasn’t answered? There is no hint that you are interested in a static universe in the question. The CMB wouldn’t exist in a static universe.

Comment: First, I do appreciate your answer, it has clarified things beyond where I was when I asked, so thanks for that. But there could easily be a static universe with a background radiation. I'm uncomfortable relying on the fact that our universe happens to be expanding to resolve this "anisotropy". Especially given the fact that Einstein referenced it; probably when he thought the universe was static.

Comment: @Rohit Pandey I understand that, but that is a new question, not at all the same as this question. I did in fact answer this question as written.  And it is upsetting to be told that I didn’t answer it.

Comment: All right, you answered it in absolute terms, but I, the OP am not completely satisfied because I have burning follow-up questions.

Comment: Yes, I understand. That is why I recommended either a posting new question here or posting on a discussion oriented forum where follow-up questions fit better with the format. A Q&A site like stack exchange is simply not designed for follow up questions. It just doesn’t fit the format